# Unable to set Background property of MenuItem for IsPressed event

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styling

I want to change the background of a MenuItem when the MenuItem is pressed.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="#FFE389" />
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.BorderBrush" Value="#C2762B" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I tried doing the above, but the trigger does not seem to work. Is the Trigger wrong?

Update: It works for the event IsMouseOver but IsPressed does not seem to work

Update 2: It works for TopLevelMenuItems but does not work for TopLevelMenuHeaderItems.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...which does not preface the property names with `MenuItem` and modify your `TargetType` and `x:Key` syntax...

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE389" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#C2762B" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your updates take a look at how a default `MenuItem` is [constructed via XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). This should get you where you need to go in providing styling for the varying parts of the `MenuItem`. Note the use of the `Role` property within the `MenuItem` style dealing with the headers and items at both the top level and sub level.

Comment: @Proximo Added reference to the default style for a MenuItem on MSDN, should get you where you need to go